# is it better to run tornado on nginx rather than running it by its own?

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

Tornado is powerful webserver and web Framework written in Python, it can run by its own (stand-alone) or could also be run through an other webserver specially nginx

Is there any performance or advantage of runing Tornado through Nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tornado can be run on its own, but there are three major advantages to using nginx as a proxy in front of it:

1. Nginx is much more efficient at serving static files.
2. A proxy makes it easier to do rolling restarts of backend processes to perform upgrades without downtime.
3. Nginx can be configured to more efficiently reject abusive requests (DDoS, etc).

Comment: what about IO Non Blocking Feature? will they still work?

Comment: Yes, the non-blocking features will still work. Note that you must use configure nginx as an http proxy (using `proxy_pass` and related settings), and *not* use uwsgi, fcgi, or any other protocols for talking to tornado.